# JQuery Mobile Div loads on page visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Please im new to Jquery/ Javascript and Jquery Mobile. I have two pages, Page One and Page two. On page two, i put a div to be hidden, only to show when a button is clicked. But whenever the link to page two is clicked from page one the div loads  automatically, but on refresh the div behaves normally.

My html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="dont_show center b">Please Wait...<br /><img src="images/loading.gif" /></div>
    <div class="b">
        <div>
            <img height="10%" width="10%" src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>      
            <input type="email" data-clear-btn="true" class="form-control" id="email" required="required" placeholder="Email Address" />
        </div>
        <div><a href="#" onclick="forgot(); return false;" class="btn btn-primary">Reset Password</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css

```
 #dont_show, .dont_show { display: none; }
```

Jquery

```
function forgot(){
    $('.b').toggle();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    if(email == '') {
        alert('Email Is Required');
        $('.b').toggle();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code
HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="dont_show center b">Please Wait...<br /><img src="images/loading.gif" /></div>
    <div class="b">
    <div>
        <img height="10%" width="10%" src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>      
        <input type="email" data-clear-btn="true" class="form-control" id="email" required="required" placeholder="Email Address" />
    </div>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Reset Password</a></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
$('.b').toggle();
var email = $('#email').val();
if(email == '') {
    alert('Email Is Required');
    $('.b').toggle();
    return;
}
});
 });
```

CSS

```
#dont_show, .dont_show { display: none; }
```